# Consume share point web service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a requirement to extract sharepoint list data through batch ETL process (Ab Initio). I have seen syntax using C# and VB sciprts. But is there any easy way by calling the the webservices using http or https URLs.
If yes, whether it requires any custom build in sharepoint to provide the web service or any built in services can be used ?

Comment: Such as [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380%28v=office.15%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can use the built-in web services from any kind of processes that supports basic HTTP operations. Of course, that does not mean a simple HTTP GET (I assume you mean that when you write

> using http or https URLs

) as you should post the details of the request in the body.

I suggest you to check the methods of the [Lists web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists(v=office.12).aspx), implement a client using C#, that performs the required action, capture the network traffic using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and reproduce the same traffic from Ab Initio. If it does not support calling SOAP web services directly, then you should create some kind of wrapper interface to make the data you need available via "pure" HTTP(S) URLs.

Comment: just a question. Does sharepoint authenciation is different for web services and accessing the portal. I am trying to figure out whether i can use the credentials to call web services users just have access to the sharepoint portal.